# Rails Comments ID => nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, rails-routing

I have a comments table and my Users comment on a movie. A comment `belongs_to :movie` and a movie `has_many :comments`

My problem is that when I create a new comment, this field has to be there `<%= f.text_field :movie_id %>`, and if I remove it, I get

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"movies", :id=>nil}`

This is the absolute path to create a new comment `http://localhost:3000/movies/:movie_id/comments/new`

I've checked the action in the movies controller and can't see anything. I've also played with the create action in the Comments controller but still nothing.

Having this field in my view can be quite confusing to the user. Does anyone have a solution for this?

This is my *comments_controller.rb*

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  before_filter :load_movie
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create,:destroy,:edit,:destroy]

  ...   

  # GET /comments/new
  # GET /comments/new.json
  def new
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    @comment = @movie.comments.new 
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comment }
    end
  end


  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create 
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment]) 
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id 
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q]) 

   respond_to do |format| 
    if @comment.save 
      @movie = @comment.movie 
      format.html { redirect_to movie_path(@movie), notice: "Comment created" } 
      format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment } 
    else 
      format.html { render action: "new" } 
      format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity } 
    end 
  end 
end

private
  def load_movie
    @movie = Movie.find_by_id(params[:movie_id])
  end
end
```

*routes.rb*

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :comments

  resources :movies do
      resources :comments, only: [:create,:destroy,:edit,:destroy,:new]
      member do 
        get 'comments'
      end
  end
end
```

*_form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.text_field :subject %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
    <%= f.text_field :movie_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
<%= f.submit "Sumbit Review" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: routes.rb file please

Comment: looks like I'll need your form too.

Comment: Take a look to [nested attributes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources :movies do
  resources :comments, only: [:create,:destroy,:edit,:destroy,:new]
end
```

will give you url like:

```
../movies/:movie_id/comments/new
```

remove that `text_field` with `movie_id` as this is not safe.

in controller create action:

```
@movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
@comment = @movie.comments.new(params[:comment]) 
@comment.user_id = current_user.id
```

not sure why you need:

```
member do 
  get 'comments'
end
```

---

**Form**

when using nested resource you'll need to build you form like this:

```
<%= form_for ([@movie, @comment]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.some_input %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I get this error `Couldn't find Movie without an ID`

I need get 'comments' as there is another page `../movies/:movie_id/comments` which displays all the comments for that movie

Comment: you can get comments there without that collection.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35317/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-18197746-rails-comments-id-nil